# python function input into string

Tags: python, python-2.7, function, variables

How can I write a function that takes in a variable and use the name of the variable to assign it as a string?

```
def one_function(dataframe):

    <does some numeric operation...>

    print('dataframe')
```

so for example

```
df_wow=pd.DataFrame([1,2,3])

one_function(df_wow)
'df_wow'

Different_data_frame=pd.DataFrame([99,98,100])
one_function(Different_data_frame)
'Different_data_frame'
```

**EDIT**

After doing some more research and with the comments and replies I came to the conclusion that it can't be done.
I got around this by just passing another argument

```
def one_function(dataframe,name_arg):
    <does some numeric operation...>

    print(name_arg)
```

My end goal here was actually to name the index of the data frame. So actually I ended up writing the following function

```
def one_function(dataframe,name_arg):

    <does some numeric operation...>

    dataframe.index.name=name_arg
    return(dataframe)
```

Comment: The question is, **what for**?

Comment: Quite simply, you can't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you cant, when passing a parameter only the *value* of the parameter is passed (copied) to the function.

However, you can achieve something similar if you use keyword arguments:

```
In [1]: def one_function(**kwargs):
   ...:     print(kwargs.keys()[0])
   ...:     

In [2]: one_function(foo=5)
foo
```

This example prints one (random) argument, if you have more than one you can loop through the `.keys()` list and print them all or do whatever you want with them.